The Coarsest Topology Which Topologizes a Group
Does there exist a coarsest topology which makes a general group $G$ a Hausdorff topological group? If so, can it be described in general, does it have a name?
In particular, I would like to show that the coarsest topology on $S_\mathbb{N},$ the bijections from $\mathbb{N}$ to itself, which (Hausdorff) topologizes it is the pointwise topology. That is, the subspace topology inherited from the product topology on $\mathbb{N}^\mathbb{N}=\prod_{n\in\mathbb{N}}\mathbb{N},$ with each copy given the discrete topology. It seems to me any coarser topology would destroy the Hausdorff structure.
For example, we would have sequences $\rho_k$ converging to $\rho$ such that for some $n\in\mathbb{N},$ $\inf_{k\in\mathbb{N}}|\rho_k(n)-\rho(n)|\geq 1.$

Trivial topology (only group itself and empty set are open) is compatible with group operation.

Without any other requirements, the coarsest topology on a group $G$ which makes it a topological group is the trivial topology $T = {G,\emptyset}$.

@mihaild What if we stipulate Hausdorff? I just edited the post.

This topology is called the minimal group topology. It does not always exist (for instance, it does not exist on the  homeomorphism group of the square). However, for every (nonempty) set $X$, the permutation group $Sym(X)$ does have a minimal group topology, namely, the topology of pointwise convergence. See
Chang, Xiao; Gartside, Paul, Minimum topological group topologies, J. Pure Appl. Algebra 221, No. 8, 2010-2024 (2017). ZBL1483.54022.
Gaughan, E. D., Topological group structure of infinite symmetric groups, Proc. Natl. Acad. Sci. USA 58, 907-910 (1967). ZBL0153.04301.
for proofs and references.

I figured the answer would be something along these lines. Thank you so much!

Theorem 3 in the second paper actually answers another question I had, so even more thanks!
